# How can I sort the contents of one file, based on the contents of another file

Tags: file, bash, sorting, debian

I have two files, one with content similar to the following:

```
1.something344343
2.something2dsdsf
4.somethingdsddfsd
5.something920j329
```

and the second file would be along the lines of:

```
1.somethingwoimewoiew
3.something9jwe90jew
7.something90kjwe90ewk
```

in essence, the first file has more numbered lines then the second one does, the first file goes up to around 39,000 lines, while the second file only goes up to 23,000 lines. Having said that, would anyone know how I could seperate the first file into line numbers (number prefacing the colon) that were included in file 2, and lines that were not included in file 2 (this would be in a bash environment). the end result would be something along the lines of this:

```
lines included in second file:
1.something344343

lines not included in second file:
2.something2dsdsf
4.somethingdsddfsd
5.something920j329
```

I've thought over different methods that I could use to do this, but unfortunately have not been able to come up with any effective solutions yet, if anyone could help out with this though I would really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: So you are only concerned with the #s that each line starts with, not whatever comes after? (i.e. If file 1 has `1.Apples; 2.Bananas` and file 2 has `1.Oranges; 3.Berries`, you want file 1 to be split into `1.Apples` and `2.Bananas`?

Comment: @sampson-chen
yep exactly, i've been processing the contents of file one, and the results are the contents of file 2, so I am trying to find a way separate what i have processed so far, and what I have not processed yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lines included in second file:

```
$ join -t"." -o 0,1.2 f1 f2
1.something344343
```

lines not included in second file:

```
$ join -t"." -v1 f1 f2
2.something2dsdsf
4.somethingdsddfsd
5.something920j329
```

Answer (score 1):

Only shows line numbers, not line contents:

```
$ diff --unchanged-group-format=$'Lines included in second file:\n%=' \
       --old-group-format=$'Lines not included in second file:\n%<' \
       --new-group-format='' \
       <(awk -F. '{print $1}' file1) <(awk -F. '{print $1}' file2)
Lines included in second file:
1
Lines not included in second file:
2
4
5
```